# "The dead" vs. "the dead people"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, definite-articles

Which one of these is correct:

> - The dead were buried near the village.
> - The dead people were buried near the village.

I tend to think that both are fine, however in my test I chose second option and got 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct. In *the dead*, *dead* functions as a noun. In *the dead people*, *dead* functions as an adjective. However, it is more common and natural to use the former.

Comment: *The dead people* sets up an implicit contrast with something else: *...the dead animals, though, were thrown in the river.*

Answer (score -1):

*The dead* means people who have died. Adding *people* on its own is redundant. If you want to use *dead* as adjective, then use *dead bodies*.

Comment: What does "Adding people ***on our own*** ..." mean?

Comment: I meant adding people as noun is not required.

Comment: Then you meant "on *on **its** own*". *Our* relates to *people*: you & at least one additional person! I suggest amending your answer.